# Keep object through orientation change but free resources when app is stopped

Tags: android, screen-orientation

When the device is rotated, the activity is completely destroyed and recreated to meet possible new resource requirements. Unfortunately this means that the `SoundPool` I use gets destroyed and the app has to reload every sound.

In my [code on GitHub](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/Furzknopf.git) I have implemented a [retained fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject), you can [check out the branch](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/Furzknopf/tree/keepWhenOrienting).

My problem is that now the SoundPool is kept loaded even if the app gets stopped. In case of this app it might not be essential but I would like to free the resources in this case.

Is there a way to keep an Object like `SoundPool` loaded **only** when runtime configuration changes occur and to **free** its resources when the app is stopped?

---

*[Note: I have completely rewritten the question to better reflect the problem.]*

Comment: In your fragment approach why not just to check `getActivity().isChangingConfigurations()` on your `onDestroy` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [tato.rodrigo pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253248/keep-object-through-orientation-change-but-free-resources-when-app-is-stopped?noredirect=1#comment52396979_32253248), the [retained fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) approach works when used with [`Activity.isChangingConfigurations`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29).

Since it is only introduced in API level 11, on older devices I have not freed the resources:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // Free resources when not restarting, if API level is appropriate.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && !getActivity().isChangingConfigurations()) {
        freeResources();
    }
}
```

Feel free to [check out the commit on GitHub](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/Furzknopf/tree/c9e77e0f51e48c94c2f7f34ddd5bac73c185a30a).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Service, move your SoundPool object to Service and in activity bind to service in onCreate and unbind in onDestroy. If activity is bound to service you could transfer commands to it using binder.

Comment: Is it possible to play sounds from a SoundPool that is in a service from the activity?

Comment: @J0hj0h, yes you can, implementation of your service must return nonnull binder, which will give you ability to interact with service, so you can properly react on touch. Or you can use LocalBroadcasts to interact with service. I see this like service loads resources in his onCreate and frees them in onDestroy. Also static SoundPool and List isn't good idea.

Comment: I just looked again at services and they seem to be designed for task running in the background independently from the activity. That is not the case here, I only want to not reload all the sounds when simply the orientation was changed. Could you also please elaborate on why `static` is not good?

Comment: @J0hj0h, 'static' variables can lead to memory leaks and unnecessary resources consumption, approach with extended Application or Service removes such problem. As intended services designed for background tasks, well playing sound seems enough background for me. In your case when you just simply need to play small files service may be overhead, but if you do not use service and do not want to use some bad solutions then you should control the configuration changes of activity yourself this will stop it from recreating.

Answer (score 0):

SoundPool isn't Parcelable (or Serializable) so you can't (easily) put it in a Bundle.

The simplest way to do what you want is to create a subclass of Application for your app, make the SoundPool an instance variable of your custom Application class and expose methods to manage the SoundPool from your Activity using a cast of getApplicationContext (the Application class is essentially a singleton that 'lives' for the duration of the app's existence).

(there probably are more elegant solutions)

Comment: I'd love to hear about those more elegant solutions. ;)